# batch file that automatically fills software code in command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, input, cmd

I am trying to write prompts to make a device do a certain action. The device has it's own syntax; however, the environment is in cmd through serial port connection. Is there a way I could write a batch file that could enter the text into the open program?

I currently have the software opened waiting for input. I just need to figure out how to input into the open application from batch file. This is what I have now.

> start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe" -load "laser"
>
> logon odin              (code that I want to be inputted into software)

Thanks for your help

Comment: [Duplicate](http://superuser.com/a/590914)?

Comment: Thank you w0xx0m! I will look into this.